# Transfer of large database from 1 server to another

Tags: sql-server

I am in the process of setting up a test environment on a server in a different location to the LIVE server.

I need to make a copy of the SQL Server database and move it across.

I want to know, if I were to Zip the Data and Log files and then split the zip file into smaller files for faster FTP. Would this damage or alter the data alignment in any way?

Comment: Did you consider compressed backup?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I'm unsure on how to do a compressed backup in SQL Server? please advise.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide sorry...I see it in the options when selecting Backup.  Will give this a try. If the file is still too large. Would zipping and splitting the zip files alter the data alignment?  Also would a compressed backup mess up the data in any way?  I'm just concerned as there are other SQL Database admins working on the database and I don't want to screw up the data. It has synchs running on multiple branches too.

Comment: @Orion if taking a backup corrupted the data, it wouldn't be a terribly useful feature. That said, if your data is *already* corrupted (hopefully you're doing regular checks for this), a backup isn't going to fix it or make it worse.

Comment: @alroc noted.  If I split a large Data or Log file into smaller pieces for FTP, could this possible corrupt the data?

Comment: Why don't you use log shipping? I migrate a 2TB database in seconds, after a good log shipping configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferring large amount (84 million rows) of data efficiently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77703/transferring-large-amount-84-million-rows-of-data-efficiently)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before you bring `ZIP` into the mix, be advised that Sql Server natively supports backing up a database to multiple files typically resulting in smaller files and faster backup time.

Check out [Backup to multiple files for faster and smaller SQL Server files](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/935/backup-to-multiple-files-for-faster-and-smaller-sql-server-files/) by Greg Robidoux.

Summarizing Greg's post:

**Problem**

> Have you ever wished you could get your backups to run faster? Well
>   there may be a way, by writing to multiple files. Creating SQL Server
>   backups is pretty simple to do; you can use the SQL Server management
>   tools or you can use T-SQL commands to issue the backup. But sometimes
>   with large databases it takes a long time to run and it is difficult
>   to copy this very large file across the network or even to your backup
>   tapes.

**Solution**

> Write your database backup to multiple files. In addition to writing
>   your database backup to one file you have the ability to write to
>   multiple files at the same time and therefore split up the workload.
>   The advantage to doing this is that the backup process can run using
>   multiple threads and therefore finish faster as well as having much
>   smaller files that can be moved across the network or copied to a CD
>   or DVD. Another advantage to writing to multiple files is if you have
>   multiple disk arrays you can write your backup files to different
>   arrays and therefore get better I/O throughput. One thing to note is
>   that to maintain the I/O throughput you should keep the writing of
>   your backup files and the reading of the database file on different
>   disk arrays.

**Backup to multiple files using T-SQL**

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Northwind] TO 
DISK = 'C:\Northwind_file1.bak', 
DISK = 'D:\Northwind_file2.bak', 
DISK = 'E:\Northwind_file3.bak', 
DISK = 'F:\Northwind_file4.bak' 
WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = 'Northwind backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT,COMPRESSION
```

On another note:

You should **SERIOUSLY** consider taking this backup with [COPY_ONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server) to make sure you don't mess up your production differential base.

Comment: That very last parameter, `WITH COMPRESSION` is worth an explicit mention as well. Using that in conjunction with backing up to multiple files should eliminate any need to use a 3rd party ZIP tool.

Answer (score 2):

You should **stripe** your backup along with compression. [Copy-dbaDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-dbadatabase/) does it for you. It stripes into 3 backup files which is sufficient in most cases.

Also, you will need to restore the database `with MOVE`

> Would this damage or alter the data alignment in any way?

No. Taking a full backup wont alter or damage data (provide your data is not corrupted or damaged).